# Laravel 5.5 pass variable to child controller return always null?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a main controller CmsController, which is extended to default Laravel controller:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
class CmsController extends Controller
{
    protected $web = null;

    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->web = Web::domain($request->domain)->first();
    }
}
```

Now, in this controller I want to call `$this->web`

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Web\PageController;
class PageController extends CmsController
{
    public function getPage(Request $request)
    {
        dd($this->web); // returns always null
    }
}
```

The data that should be returned is 100% correct, request parameters are also there.

Can someone give me a idea, what I did wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried by executing parent constructor.. ?

Comment: @GautamPatadiya many thanks for your idea, it was exactly solution what I wanted :) I added in my construct method: parent::__construct($request);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to execute parent constructor:

```
class PageController extends CmsController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
         parent::__construct();
         ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you can't access the session or authenticated user in your controller's constructor because the middleware has not run yet, and even if you did the `dd($this->web);` in the CmsController construct you will get null So you can do it like this :

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
class CmsController extends Controller
{
    protected $web = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
            $this->web = Web::domain($request->domain)->first();
            return $next($request);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Good Answer, but better to create a Middleware class 

Comment: No need for one it just intersept the request via the `middleware` method :)

Comment: It is needed for clean code, single responsibility and readability.

Comment: Ok even if you create a new one you will need to call `$this->middleware` method in the controller construct because the middleware has not run yet !

Comment: I don't say to remove the `$this->middleware` part, just to create a Middleware class and call it there :)

Answer (score 0):

You are extending `CmsController` and using `PageController` thats why ,

```
 use App\Http\Controllers\Web\CmsController;

 class PageController extends CmsController
 {
     public function getPage(Request $request)
     {
       dd($this->web); // returns always null
     }
 }
```

I have changed,

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Web\PageController;
```

to this,

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Web\CmsController;
```